# CodeIgniter: Define routes.

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am giving

```
$route['admin/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/(:any)'] = "pages/$1/id_$2";
```

Where pages is controller and the function is message. And in view I have give path as

```
<a title="View" href="<?php echo site_url("admin"); ?>/message/<?php echo base64_encode(convert_uuencode($row['id'])); ?>"><button class="btn btn-xs btn-info" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i></button></a>
```

It's not working and the error is page not found.

Comment: Give link generated in anchor link .....

Comment: Can you comment the link generated in href?